# Cannot apply filter to image

Tags: cocoa, osx-mavericks, core-image, quartz-core

I need to apply CIZoomBlur with default values to image. I'm doing it with the following code:

```
NSURL   * url   = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: @"galaxy.png"];
CIImage * image = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL: url];
CIContext *context = [[CIContext alloc] init];
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIZoomBlur"];
[filter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
CGRect extent = [result extent];
CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:extent];
NSImage *image2 = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage size:NSSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(640, 1136))];
self.imageView.image = image2;
```

In log I can see:

```
/SourceCache/CoreImage/CoreImage-9.2.8/API/CIFilter.mm:594: CIZoomBlur apply:: Caught exception: CIZoomBlur: id: nil value for argument #0 (src)
```

Image is located inside project. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you actually checked if `image` is not `nil` ?

Comment: It is not     nil    . I've checked

Comment: If the file is located within the app bundle then using `NSURL fileURLWithPath` will **not** locate it.  The image must be `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right code is:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"galaxy" ofType:@"png"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
CIImage * image = [CIImage imageWithData:data];
CIContext *context = [[CIContext alloc] init];
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIZoomBlur"];
[filter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
CGRect extent = [result extent];
CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:extent];
NSImage *image2 = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage size:NSSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(640, 1136))];
self.imageView.image = image2;
```

If the file is located within the app bundle then using NSURL fileURLWithPath will not locate it. The image must be nil. Thanks to [trojanfoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299924/trojanfoe)